# Jackson - hibernate entities serialization

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson

I want to serialize and deserialize hibernate entities that contains other entities into flat JSON format.
So let's say I have the following entities:

Key:

```
@Entity
public class Key implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "KeyID")
private Long id;

@Column
private String description;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "KeyTypeID", nullable = false)
private KeyType keyType;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public KeyType getKeyType() {
    return keyType;
}

public void setKeyType(KeyType keyType) {
    this.keyType = keyType;
}
}
```

KeyType:

```
@Entity
public class KeyType implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "KeyTypeID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "Name", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String name;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

I want to serialize objects of Key class into:

```
{
    "keyID": 1,    
    "description": "key 1",
    "keyTypeName": "Type 5" //this is Key.keyType.name
}
```

I also want to be able to deserialize above JSON into Key object containing KeyType entity.
Is that possible using Jackson or do I need to implement custom code?

Comment: For this specific case, you need to use a custom serialized/deserializer http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

I'm not sure if this use case is supported in Jackson, but below is an example of how you could do this using MOXy's `@XmlPath` extension.

**Key**

By specifying `@XmlPath(".")` the contents of the reference object are pulled up into the node corresponding to the source object.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@Entity
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Key implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "KeyID")
    @XmlElement(name="keyID")
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "KeyTypeID", nullable = false)
    @XmlPath(".")
    private KeyType keyType;

}
```

**KeyType**

The `@XmlElement` annotation is leveraged to map to a JSON key.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

@Entity
public class KeyType implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "KeyTypeID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "Name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @XmlElement(name="keyTypeName")
    private String name;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

The demo code below with convert your JSON document to/from your domain model.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Key.class}, properties);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StreamSource json = new StreamSource("src/forum13819583/input.json");
        Key key = unmarshaller.unmarshal(json, Key.class).getValue();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(key, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.json/Output**

```
{
    "keyID": 1,    
    "description": "key 1",
    "keyTypeName": "Type 5" 
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html